# Password Special Charecter issue in mongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Error : Password Special Character issue in mongoDB

Code:

```
connstr="mongodb://test:test@123@67.186.193.192:27017/testdb"
```

Here i changed password "test@123" to "test%4123" . Because @ ASCII code is %4
Now it is working fine.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connstr); //vss
var server = client.GetServer();

//server.Ping();
var db = client.GetDatabase(dbname);
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> collections = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var tableviewset = JArray.Parse(db.ListCollectionsAsync().Result.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>().Result.ToJson());
```

But my users will use different passwords like $,^,*,( ... etc. So in this situation what i do ?

Comment: @serpent5 i found the issue it is Password issue. So i need a  solution for above question...

Comment: obviously encode the url... read the docs, google, analyse and execute...

Comment: Where do the usernames, passwords, etc, come from? Are they in a configuration file?

Comment: @serpent5 yes we create subusers under root user any database in mongodb right.. At that time that users password will have special charterers it will cause a issue in mongoclient connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somthing like this , you can user MongoClientSettings for password and all other parameter.

```
 private MongoClientSettings GetSecuritySettingForConnection()
        {
            MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
            settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, port);
            MongoIdentity identity = new MongoInternalIdentity(authenticationDatabase, userName);
            MongoIdentityEvidence evidence = new PasswordEvidence(password);
            settings.Credentials = new List<MongoCredential>()
            {
                new MongoCredential("SCRAM-SHA-1", identity, evidence)

            };
            settings.MaxConnectionIdleTime = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
            return settings;
        }
```

After that You can this function over here:

```
 var client = new MongoClient(GetSecuritySettingForConnection());
```

Let me know if any confusion.